# Select dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've had some luck with Shiny and R, but I can't get an selectInput function to change the dataframe. I'm probably missing something obvious, but here's my code

```
require(shiny)

A <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,2,1))
B <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,5),y=c(3,5,0))

ui <- fluidPage(

selectInput("df", "Select dataframe", choices = c('A'='A','B'='B'), selected = 'A'),

plotOutput("Plot")

)

server <- function(input, output)
{

  df <- reactive({
 x <- as.data.frame(input$df)
  })

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
  df <- df()
  plot(x=df$x, y=df$y)

})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant use `as.data.frame` and name of df

try to use `get`

```
A <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,2,1))
B <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,5),y=c(3,5,0))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df <- reactive({
    x <- get(input$df)
  })

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    df <- df()
    plot(x=df$x, y=df$y)

  })
})
```

Comment: That's it! Many thanks! I rarely use get() in base R so I'd completely forgotten. I'd tried paste(), but not get()